# Get trigger from ContentObserver

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

Is there a way to tell why a ContentObserver was triggered? For example, if I am monitoring SMS via the "content://sms" URI and an SMS is sent or received, is there a way to deduce, within the ContentObserver class, what the SMS type is (I know I can set N ContentObservers, specifying different URI's, but I am hoping there is a way to tell from the ContentObserver class)?

BONUS: There is also a fun subtlety:

The 2nd method is only available from API level 16 onwards, so the code should not rely on a URI to work properly.

ContentObserver:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, 
                   new MessageObserver(new Handler(), getBaseContext()));
```

ContentObserver Class:

```
class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {     
   public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
      super(handler);           
   }

   @Override
   public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
      this.onChange(selfChange, null);
      // What SMS type caused this to trigger????????

   }        

   @Override
   public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
      // What SMS type caused this to trigger????????
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See you will receive Onchange in below mentioned cases

1. If any syncadapter is active upon that database then it will trigger onchange each time it pefrom sync, in this case you might receive onchange even if nothing is actually changed.
2. If there is actaul change in dataset.

Now coming to figuring out data which was changed, setting a observer for each possible URI is not at all good idea, with this you can although detect update or delete scenarios but sensing new insert will be a problem. I will suggest you following

Keep a single observer, upon initialization you can process entire data which is avilable initially, keep remebering column_id,update_timestamp and total row count once you progress forward, when onchange come next time with Coulmn_Id,update_timestamp and count you can figure out kind of change that was occured

--> Look for any rows having column_id greater then what you remeber, if it return any rows then certainly some new rows are inserted you can query them specifically
--> if above criteria fails then you need to look for update_timespamp any thing greater then last you remeber will tell if about rows that were updated
--> If both of above cirteria fial then look for difference in count which might tell you about delete operation.

if none of above occurs, clearly it was nothing then just ignore onchange signal. Hope it helps.