# Where to find xamarin android's implementation of the download provider

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-download-manager

I implemented the download functionality in my app, and now I want to update the app's UI with the download percentage. From the docs, I see that a content provider is to be used. I came accross this download content provider: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/445b908/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadProvider.java
But the issue is, Xamarin seems not to have it. So I wish to know if it is available in an external package.
I tried implementing my own content provider as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442743/content-observer-doesnt-monitor-the-downloadmanagers-download-progress-on-andr), but its observer never gets called. Can someone please help ?

Comment: For now, i do not find the native example on official document. Please check the code in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/212514/how-to-check-download-manager-file-downloaded-and.html

Comment: Hi, thanks but I've already implemented that part. My aim is to monitor the download progress in app, and not only be notified when download terminates.

Comment: Have you try the while loop for the percentage? Check the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230339/showing-download-percentage-with-download-manager

Comment: I have tried something better, that is; using xamarin forms' timer and it works better. But my aim is to find out why these providers and observers do not work.

Comment: Could you make sure the content change occurs? And when onChange do not sent which user have been changed,  we need to check how to match it with your data. This post is too old. But it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101814/get-trigger-from-contentobserver